# Why min-height 100% is not working for my div?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have issue with my css code. I have to set min-height for my slider at minimum 100% height but this not working as I except. Why?

I need this becouse I have to put text inside my slider and if the height of screen is not enought I need area of slider automatic expand. So this means the whole page should work as slider at minimum 100% height of browser but if not enought place the slider should automatic expand.... I hope I explain it enought. Thx for help...

MyCodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hooks-vvgf3?file=/index.html

My Code

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.container-fluid{
    min-height: 100%;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators, .carousel-item{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/18e42a7034.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newStyle.css">
    <title>SPŠIT | DOD</title></head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/slider-electro.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/slider-engineer.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/slider-ist.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```#carouselExampleIndicators, .carousel-item{
    min-height: 100vh;
}```

Comment: This is my real project: https://younglocal.sk .... When yo uresize it to mobile version - when height is very low you will see this advise not work as You will excepting

Answer (score 1):

Use vh (relative to the height of the viewport) units instead of %, vh is relative to the screen height.

example:

```
.carousel-item {     
  min-height: 100vh; 
}
```

Comment: Look at this page please. This is my real project. I used it like you wrote before. But when you resize HEIGHT (f.e. mobile resolution) the text overflowing and container not  expanding. :( https://younglocal.sk

Comment: @YoungL. you don't have that class in your web page, did you copy that as is? If yes then it won't work, you need to add it to the element which is present in the webpage

Comment: `.carousel-item{ min-height: 100vh; }` this one is what you need I believe!

Comment: No I exaclty did this and when height is lesser then text + img height it cut my text + button in lower height resoution. :/